# Running unit tests outside of VS developer command prompt?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, command-prompt

***Question Background:***

I have produced a batch file that runs the .dll of my unit test project. Running this in the Visual Studio developers command prompt works perfectly. I now want to be able to run this batch file through the standard MS-DOS command prompt.

***The issue:***

this is the current batch file command:

```
cd C:\Users\Me\Desktop\WebService\CalcUnitTests

MSTest/testcontainer:C:\Users\Me\Desktop\WebService\Calc\CalcUnitTests\bin\Debug\CalcUnitTests.dll
```

Running the above batch file command on the MS-DOS NON-Developer prompt produces an error of:

```
'MSTest' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**How can I run the above batch file through the standard command prompt?** Any info would be most helpful.

***Edit:***

I have now updated my Environment variables but still recieve the same unrecognized 'MSTest' error when running the batch file:

[image]

Comment: Use the full path to MSTest.exe because MSTest.exe is not a standard windows command rather it is a command line utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to find the path to MSTest, which is dependent on the version of Visual Studio you have installed and then you need to add that path to your PATH Environment variables so that the MSTest command is available to any application, include the non-dev MS-DOS command prompt.

The path should look something like this:

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have added the variable name PATH along with the value of '%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe' and am still receiving the MS TEST error message on the batch file.

Comment: Did you restart your machine?I'm pretty sure that sometimes Envirnomental variable changes don't take effect until a restart. Unfortunately I cannot verify this as I'm at my work!

Also, you need to add it to your **System Variables -> Path**

Comment: I think you just need to close & re-open the Command prompt (environment variables are loaded when cmd.exe starts running).